# Facebook Graph Api - Access token for Test Page with developer or admin account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a Facebook App for posting to a page using the Graph Api. To be able to test this I created a Test User and Test Page.

Now I want to create a Page Access token which I can use when making the Graph Api requests. As is described on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/test-pages this should be possible with an admin or developer account.

[image]

If I get an access token for my Test User from the developer portal I can see the Test User has access to the page using the '/me/accounts' request. Although when I do the same for my admin account the Test Page isn't listed when making the '/me/accounts' request.

Am I missing something? Should I add my admin account to the Test Page somewhere?

Comment: I am not sure you _can_ add your admin account to a test page, quote from the very same documentation page you linked to: _"Test pages cannot interact with real Facebook users"_

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think you are right about that because when I try to add my my admin account to the Test Page it cannot be found. Still wondering on how to get  a Page Access token for my admin account though. As the document do state it should possible.

Comment: I don't see it explicitly say that anywhere. If you are referring to the comment at the bottom where it says admins can use the user accounts endpoint to get page IDs and token, I am guessing that means use that endpoint with the test user's ID, not that of the admin itself.

Comment: Hi @CBroe, I think you might be right about that. I got it working with retrieving a Page access token for the Test User. I misinterpreted what was stated in the documentation. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments from @CBroe, I realized I  misinterpreted what was stated in the documentation.

It is not possible to get a Page Access Token for the Test page as your own Admin/Developer account. So you'll just have to use the Page Access Token that can be requested as the Test user itself.